# how to write regex for java replaceall function?

Tags: java, regex, replace, replaceall

I have  String variable containing string like

```
{IF {FILLIN  PDPremium  \* MERGEFORMATPDPremium }= " 0.00" "" "Property DamageSectionInsured ItemsSum Insured( {FILLIN  si_curr  \* MERGEFORMATsi_curr })Premium( {FILLIN  si_curr  \* MERGEFORMATsi_curr }) {FILLIN  covg_desc_temp  \* MERGEFORMATcovg_desc_temp } {FILLIN  covg_si  \* MERGEFORMATcovg_si } {FILLIN  covg_prem  \* MERGEFORMATcovg_prem }"pol_tc_cdpol_tc_desc }
```

I want to replace

```
{FILLIN  PDPremium  \* MERGEFORMATPDPremium } `{FILLIN  covg_si  \* MERGEFORMATcovg_si }
```

`{PDPremium  }{covg_si }`

```
FILLIN  PDPremium  \* MERGEFORMAT
```

with empty `""`

how to write regular expression 
 My program is like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "IF {FILLIN  PDPremium  \\* MERGEFORMATPDPremium }";
    System.out.println(a.replaceAll( "(?i)(FILLIN[^>]*?\\sMERGEFORMAT\\s*)", "" ));

}
```

Comment: `{FILLIN  PDPremium  \* MERGEFORMATPDPremium }` -> `{PDPremium }` i want like this

Comment: Please understand when to use REGEX and when not . if you want to replace a String literal , use string#replace with the String literal as the argument

Comment: i have many occurrence like this `{FILLIN  PDPremium  \* MERGEFORMATPDPremium }` need to replace all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
String p = "FILLIN [^\\\\]+\\\\\\\* MERGEFORMAT";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll(p , "" ));
```

Comment: PDPremium  can be any thing